# Random shuffle inquiry

Tags: c++, shuffle, poker

Making a poker game, doing basics now created a vector struct with my values, shuffling it, and then printing out 5 "cards". My problem is that when I press "2" to deal again, it gives me same cards. I simply just want it to grab ANOTHER 5 cards from my array and keep doing so until there is not enough cards to deal again, and then for it to reshuffle and continue. Here's what I have so far, and it does what I said, it shuffles and then prints out 5 different cards, but if I press deal again I get the same 5 cards unless I shuffle again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "ctime"
#include "cstdlib"
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int number;
    string suit;
    struct node *info;
};

vector<node> deckArray();
void displayDeal();
void Start();
vector<node> Deck(52);

int main()
{
    Start();
}

void Start()
{
    int choice;
    int choice2;

    deckArray();
    Deck.push_back(node());

    for (int s = 0; s < 2; ++s)
        Deck[0].number = s;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("1. Shuffle.\n");
        printf("2. Deal.\n");
        printf("2. Exit.");
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nAdding a hand!\n");
                deckArray();
                //Shuffle(Deck);
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                {
                    printf("\n%d", Deck[i].number);
                    printf("%s\n", Deck[i].suit.c_str());
                }
                cin.get();
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("\n Invalid Choice. \n");
                break;
        }
    }
}

vector<node> deckArray()
{
    Deck[0].number = 2;
    Deck[0].suit = "S";
    Deck[1].number = 2;
    Deck[1].suit = "H";
    Deck[2].number = 2;
    Deck[2].suit = "D";
    Deck[3].number = 2;
    Deck[3].suit = "C";
    //2
    Deck[4].number = 3;
    Deck[4].suit = "S";
    Deck[5].number = 3;
    Deck[5].suit = "H";
    Deck[6].number = 3;
    Deck[6].suit = "D";
    Deck[7].number = 3;
    Deck[7].suit = "C";
    //3
    Deck[8].number = 4;
    Deck[8].suit = "S";
    Deck[9].number = 4;
    Deck[9].suit = "H";
    Deck[10].number = 4;
    Deck[10].suit = "D";
    Deck[11].number = 4;
    Deck[11].suit = "C";
    //4
    Deck[12].number = 5;
    Deck[12].suit = "D";
    Deck[13].number = 5;
    Deck[13].suit = "C";
    Deck[14].number = 5;
    Deck[14].suit = "D";
    Deck[15].number = 5;
    Deck[15].suit = "C";
    //5
    Deck[16].number = 6;
    Deck[16].suit = "D";
    Deck[17].number = 6;
    Deck[17].suit = "C";
    Deck[18].number = 6;
    Deck[18].suit = "D";
    Deck[19].number = 6;
    Deck[19].suit = "C";
    //6
    Deck[20].number = 7;
    Deck[20].suit = "D";
    Deck[21].number = 7;
    Deck[21].suit = "C";
    Deck[22].number = 7;
    Deck[22].suit = "D";
    Deck[23].number = 7;
    Deck[23].suit = "C";
    //7
    Deck[24].number = 8;
    Deck[24].suit = "D";
    Deck[25].number = 8;
    Deck[25].suit = "C";
    Deck[26].number = 8;
    Deck[26].suit = "D";
    Deck[27].number = 8;
    Deck[27].suit = "C";
    //8
    Deck[28].number = 9;
    Deck[28].suit = "D";
    Deck[29].number = 9;
    Deck[29].suit = "C";
    Deck[30].number = 9;
    Deck[30].suit = "D";
    Deck[31].number = 9;
    Deck[31].suit = "C";
    //9
    Deck[32].number = 10;
    Deck[32].suit = "D";
    Deck[33].number = 10;
    Deck[33].suit = "C";
    Deck[34].number = 10;
    Deck[34].suit = "D";
    Deck[35].number = 10;
    Deck[35].suit = "C";
    //10
    Deck[36].number = 11; //need to convert to string "J"
    Deck[36].suit = "D";
    Deck[37].number = 11;
    Deck[37].suit = "C";
    Deck[38].number = 11;
    Deck[38].suit = "D";
    Deck[39].number = 11;
    Deck[39].suit = "C";
    //11 (J)
    Deck[40].number = 12; //need to convert to string "Q"
    Deck[40].suit = "D";
    Deck[41].number = 12;
    Deck[41].suit = "C";
    Deck[42].number = 12;
    Deck[42].suit = "D";
    Deck[43].number = 12;
    Deck[43].suit = "C";
    //12 (Q)
    Deck[44].number = 13; //need to convert to string "K"
    Deck[44].suit = "D";
    Deck[45].number = 13;
    Deck[45].suit = "C";
    Deck[46].number = 13;
    Deck[46].suit = "D";
    Deck[47].number = 13;
    Deck[47].suit = "C";
    //13 (K)
    Deck[48].number = 14; //need to convert to string "A"
    Deck[48].suit = "D";
    Deck[49].number = 14;
    Deck[49].suit = "C";
    Deck[50].number = 14;
    Deck[50].suit = "D";
    Deck[51].number = 14;
    Deck[51].suit = "C";

    random_shuffle(Deck.begin(), Deck.end());
    return Deck;
}
```

1 solution to my problem, however not sure if this is a programmer no-no or not

```
case 2:
    addToShuffle();
    break;

void addToShuffle()
{
for (int i = x; i < z; ++i)
{
    printf("\n%d", Deck[i].number);
    printf("%s\n", Deck[i].suit.c_str());
}
x += 5;
z += 5;
cin.get();
}
```

Comment: [OT]: `struct node *info;` is unused in `node` and may be removed.

Comment: right now it is, we are going to eventually make this into an app so we put that there for the time being.

Comment: Side note: I almost feel guilty breaking this to you, but you can do this considerably simpler using a simple `std::vector<int>` and two arrays of constraint strings for your suits and ranks. It would also eliminate about 90% of the posted code. Ping if you want to know how.

Comment: No I already am aware of that. We made a poker game before with that, but we are learning about structs now and I think a struct is an easier way to create a check system (I am still a student). I do appreciate that though, it was easier before doing it with those 2 seperate vectors.

Comment: @user3308129 its actually only one vector (of int), the static constants are there just for display. So long as you already know. Simple is better. mmmk.

Comment: Why does your `deckArray()` return a `vector<node>` when the return is (a) ignored and (b) a global variable which `deckArray` manipulates directly? Wouldn't it be better to have `deckArray` do what it needs to do in a local vector, which it returns, and which the caller assigns or uses as he sees fit?

Comment: @NikBougalis My apologies, I am not new to C++, but I am still not above Intermediate yet. I thought I had to return the vector<struct> because it shuffled Deck so I thought I had to, but I guess not. Will fix, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case 2` just prints the first 5 cards, without removing them from the deck...
So dealing a new time (without shuffle) will still return the same cards.

[OT] `deckArray` may be rewritten as follow:

```
vector<node> deckArray()
{
    vector<node> cards(52);
    const char* colors[4] = {"S", "H", "D", "C"};

    int i = 0;
    for (int v = 2; v != 15; ++v) {
        for (int c = 0; c != 4; ++c, ++i) {
            cards[i].number = v;
            cards[i].suit = colors[c];
        }
    }
    random_shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end());
    return cards;
}
```

Comment: how would I remove them from the deck then?

Comment: `Deck.erase(Deck.begin(), Deck.begin() + 5);` may do the job, but you may want to copy cards in some `hands[currentPlayer]` first...

Comment: What do you think of my edit in my OP? Is that a good way to do it or might I run into problems later doing it that way?

Comment: As `z` seem useless, you may use `x + 5` directly. And you may have problem when there is not enough cards in deck.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you only ever deal cards 0-4 from the vector. If you don't change the vector between deals, then those elements will always be the same. There are two obvious ways to fix that.

Probably the best approach is to keep track of how many cards you've already dealt, and start there on the next deal. For example, the first time it will start dealing from 0, and store somewhere that the next available card is at index 5. The second time, it will start dealing from 5, and so on.

An alternative approach is to pop each card from the vector as you deal it (and optionally add it to a second 'discard' vector). That way, the deck will get smaller every time you deal, until there are no cards left. That approach is easier in some ways, but it means you'd have to resize and repopulate the deck every time you shuffle it.